# How do I access elements from an array of arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For example my array of arrays looks like this:

```
[["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 280],["RDP-ATTACK", 528]]
```

The arrays are referencing a type of exploit, and the count of how many times it has occurred (based on IPS).

What method is used to pull elements from this array?

Comment: Is it actually `[["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 280],["RDP-ATTACK", 528]]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access all the elements, and not a specific element:

```
[["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 280],["RDP-ATTACK", 528]].each do |exploit,count|
  p "exploit: #{exploit}, count: #{count}"
end

=> "exploit: WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK, count: 280"
   "exploit: RDP-ATTACK, count: 528"
```

Answer (score 2):

Multi-dimension arrays are accessed like so:

```
[2] pry(main)> array = [["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 280],["RDP-ATTACK", 528]]
=> [["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 280], ["RDP-ATTACK", 528]]
[3] pry(main)> array[0]
=> ["WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK", 280]
[4] pry(main)> array[0][0]
=> "WEB-APPLICATION-ATTACK"
[5] pry(main)> array[0][1]
=> 280
[6] pry(main)> array[1][0]
=> "RDP-ATTACK"
[7] pry(main)> array[1][1]
=> 528
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to call

```
array[index of inner array][index of element in inner array]
```